# Access variable passed to template from JavaScript in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm passing variables to template:

```
{{> myTemplate myVariable}}
```

Inside myTemplate I access it with:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{this}}
</template>
```

Where `this` will be `myVariable`

How can I access `myVariable`  from the code - onCreated, onRendered, helpers of myTemplate.

Example:

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  // How access myVariable here?
});
```

or

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function(){
  // How access myVariable here?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the onCreated and onRendered callbacks, `this.data` points to the passed data:

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  console.log(this.data);
});

Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function(){
  console.log(this.data);
});
```